# Python: Re-implementing `from module import *`

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, callstack

I have this `flood` function which floods the namespace of the caller with all global variables defined in the same module as `flood`:

```
# test.py
import inspect

a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
def flood():
    inspect.getmodule(inspect.stack()[-1][0]).__dict__.update(globals())
```

When invoked from another module, e.g.

```
# main.py
import test

test.flood()
print(a, b, c)
```

calling `test.flood()` is equivalent to doing `from test import *`. Having this functionality wrapped up in a function comes in handy when working with Cython, where - if `test.py` has been compiled - `from test import *` does not import variables declared at the C level.

One difference between this hack and the proper `from test import *` is that the hack does not work from an interactive Python shell. Here, the frame object obtained by `inspect.stack()[-1][0]` does not belong to a module, and so `inspect.getmodule(inspect.stack()[-1][0])` returns `None`.

How can I extend the hack so that `flood()` can flood the global namespace  in an interactive Python shell as well?

Comment: Why are you using `*` imports in the first place? Explicit is better than implicit, y'know.

Comment: `*` *does* have its usages. I have a large framework where one particular module implements 100+ variables and functions, which is used a lot by all other modules in the framework.